# Parsing a command line and replacing a character using pointers in C

Tags: c, parsing

I am writing a simple shell. I wrote a parser to tokenize the command line to send it to `execvp`. I would like to check for the character `&` while parsing and replace it by `\0`. I am working with pointers and am slightly confused on how to proceed. Here is my parser code:

```
void  parseArgs(char *input, char **args, int *background)
{
    while (*input != '\0') {
        while (*input == ' ' || *input == '\t' || *input == '\n')
           *input++ = '\0';                               /* replace empty spaces */
        *args++ = input;                                /* save argument position */
        while (*input != '\0' && *input != ' ' && 
               *input != '\t' && *input != '\n')
            input++;                      /* read argument until next empty space */
    }
    *args = NULL;                                     /* end of the argument list */
}
```

Since I am using pointer, I'm having difficulties replacing what I want. Should I use an array equivalent of the above instead, or is there an easy fix? Basically, I would like my code to switch `background` to `1` if `&` is read, then replace this character by `\0`. Is there a way to replace a character only using pointers?

Comment: Please just use `strtok` or better `strtok_r`. It's far less error-prone.

Comment: @abligh You're very right sir, but just to mention, `strtok_r()` is not standard C, it is a compiler extension, mostly.

Comment: @SouravGhosh incorrect. It is a POSIX function: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok_r.html

Comment: Can `strtok` use multiple delimiters?

Comment: @iHubble yes. Any character in the delimiter string is a delimiter.

Comment: @abligh: `strtok_r` is not standard C. The link you posted says: "Extension to the ISO C standard.
The functionality described is an extension to the ISO C standard. Application developers may make use of an extension as it is supported on all POSIX.1-2008-conforming systems."

Comment: @abligh Sir, in the above link it's mentioned like `The functionality described is an extension to the ISO C standard. Application developers may make use of an extension as it is supported on all POSIX.1-2008-conforming systems.`. So where did i go wrong, can you please elaborate a bit? Thanks.

Comment: @Sourav My understanding it is that it is *now* part of POSIX.1-2001; prior to that it was introduced in IEEE Std 1003.1c-1995 (aka POSIX.1c) which was *then* an extension of IEEE Std 1003.1-1988 (aka POSIX.1). It was added as `strtok` was not re-entrant. However, under no circumstance is it or was it ever 'a compiler extension'. It's nothing to do with the compiler; it's in the C library.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I hope I'm not being obtuse but I can't find that wording on the link I posted. Rather it says *The `strtok_r()` function is included for alignment with the POSIX Threads Extension.* - given two of you have said the same thing, this is very peculiar. The text I see is at: http://pastebin.com/ssNNh8D2 - I've even pasted and ran the text through `grep`.

Comment: Yes, as it says, `strtok_r` is a POSIX only **extension**. It is **not standard** C. If you click the [CX] link, you will find the text we posted.

Answer (score 0):

Despite my comment re `strtok` yours is not a bad attempt at a parser. Note it doesn't check that you don't overrun the end of `**args`.

Part of your issue is your problem is not well defined. Do you want to check whether the last character of your last argument is `&`? (if so, at the end of the argument processing, fix it). Or do you want to count `&` as a terminating delimiter and count everything before that as one command, and everything after that as another? In that case, the best thing to do would be to preprocess the string, replacing `&` by `\0`, *then* call `parseArgs`, run your shell, and when you've done, pick up from where you got to (so `foo & bar & baz` works). However, in a real shell you can do things like `2>&1` as an I/O redirect. To get things like that working, you will probably be best of tokenizing properly. To do that yacc/lex are your friends.

Edit - to check the `&` right at the end, immediately before `*args = NULL` do something like:

```
int lenlast = strlen (*args);
if ((*args)[lenlast] = '&')
{
    (*args)[lenlast] = '\0';
    background = 1; /* declare that somewhere */
}
```

Comment: I would like to check if `&` is the last character. I will not be dealing with the case `foo & bar & baz`. How do I check this at the end of the argument processing?